# my span tag is not updating when appending 0 or changing 0 to 12 in clock

Tags: javascript

Span tag is not updating when appending 0 if hour < 10 (e.g 9 = 09) and if hour == 0 (e.g 00 = 12) but it shows in console.log that it changed:

```
function showTime(){
    const date = new Date();
    const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    let d = document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];
    let h = document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = date.getHours();
    let m = document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = date.getMinutes();
    let s = document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = date.getSeconds();


    if(h == 0){
      h = 12;
    }

    if(h > 12){
      h -= 12
    }

    h = h < 10 ? "0"+h :h;
    m = m < 10 ? "0"+m :m;
    s = s < 10 ? "0"+s :s;


    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
    console.log(m);
}

showTime();
```

Comment: `h = "0" + h;` prepends `0` to variable `h` ... doesn't do anything to `document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML` ... suggest you add `document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = h` after the `if` logic

Comment: omg that was quick it solved my problem! tnx alot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Set the `innerHTML` of your span elements after the calculations, not before.

Here is a fixed and simplified version using ternaries instead of `if` statements and a `pad` function:

```js
function showTime(){
    const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    const date = new Date();
    let h = date.getHours();
    let m = date.getMinutes();
    let s = date.getSeconds();
    
    const pad = x => x < 10 ? '0' + x : x;
    
    h = h === 0 ? 12 : h;
    h = h > 12 ? h - 12 : h;
    
    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = pad(h);
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = pad(m);
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = pad(s);

    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
}

showTime();
```

```html
<span id="day"></span>&nbsp;
<span id="hour"></span>:<span id="minute"></span>:<span id="second"></span>
```